# @Html.DropDownList set default text with value

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

```
 @Html.DropDownList("LOCATION_ID", new SelectList(ViewBag.Locations, "LOCATION_ID", "LOCATION_NAME"),"--Select Location--", new { @class = "select-drop form-control" })
```

In view I am using this drop downlist coding.While running this, in options tag value for text "--Select Location--" is empty but i want it to be 0.

Can anyone tell me how to define?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The whole purpose of the 3rd parameter (`"--Select Location--"`)` is to create a `null` option so it can be used for validation (using a `[Required]` attribute). Why would you want to give to a value of `0`? (that makes no sense and is only going to create other issues)

Comment: @StephenMuecke as it is not mandatory field if not selected i want to insert 0

Comment: Then remove the `"--Select Location--"` and add a new item in `ViewBag.Locations` (but what your doing is awful practice. Use a view model that contains a property `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Locations` and strongly bind to you model using `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.LOCATION_ID, Model.Locations)`